# Prepared statements: Function outputs nothing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

What I wanna do, is to echo all rows from `subjects table`.

P.S. Recently installed Xdebug, now php logs errors but in this case there is no error in error log.

My function looks like that. Outputs nothing.

```
function genSubjectsList() {
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`, `subject` FROM `subjects`") or die($db->error);
    $row = array();
    stmt_bind_assoc($stmt, $row);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' value='" . $row[0] . "' name='subjects' id='subjects'/>" . $row[1] . "\n";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

What's wrong with this func?

Comment: Can't find any reference to `stmt_bind_assoc` on PHP.net, and my IDE isn't picking it up either. Is it a custom function you wrote?. Which DB interface you using? PDO, mysqli, mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested, gleaned from [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)):

```
function genSubjectsList()
{
    global $db;
    $row = array();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`, `subject` FROM `subjects`") or die($db->error);
    $stmt->execute();        
    $stmt->bind_result($row);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' value='" . $row[0] . "' name='subjects' id='subjects'/>" . $row[1] . "\n";
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's all that you need. Tested

```
function genSubjectsList() {
    global $db;


    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`, `subject` FROM `subjects`") or die($db->error);

    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);

    /* bind variables to prepared statement */
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $subject)  or die($stmt->error);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' value='" . $id . "' name='subjects' id='subjects'/>" . $subject . "\n";
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```